# MBean "jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/,host=localhost" not found

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, mbeans

I'm trying to access the **JBoss v4.2** MBean registered as

```
jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/,host=localhost
```

using the following code:

```
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/,host=localhost");
ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer().getAttribute(name, "activeSessions");
```

But this code keeps throwing the following exception:

```
javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/,host=localhost is not registered.
```

On the other hand I'm able to see and use this bean using the jmx-console via ...//localhost:8080/jmx-console/ - the MBean is available.

[image: Screenshot]

***What else is necessary to access the same MBean via code?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it...

```
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Manager,path=/,host=localhost");
this.sessions = new Long((Integer) MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss().getAttribute(name, "activeSessions"));
```

I had to find the right MBeanServer... `MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss()` solves it.